# How to solve this kind of function equation

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, inequality

Let $ f $ be a differentiable real-valued function defined on $ [ 0 , 1 ] $, stisfying the following conditions:
$$ f ( 1 ) = e f ( 0 ) $$
$$ \int _ 0 ^ 1 \left( \frac { f ' ( x ) } { f ( x ) } \right) ^ 2 \mathrm d x \le 1 $$
Prove that there is a constant real number $ c $ such that $ f ( x ) = c e ^ x $.

I think we first need to prove $ f ' ( x ) = f ( x ) $.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I Will try to do

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By Jensen's Inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
\log\!\left(\frac{f(1)}{f(0)}\right)^2
&=\left(\int_0^1\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\\
&\le\int_0^1\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\\[9pt]
&\le1
\end{align}
$$

---

Since $f(1)=e\,f(0)$, we also have $\log\!\left(\frac{f(1)}{f(0)}\right)^2=1$. Since $x\mapsto x^2$ is strictly convex, equality in Jensen's Inequality means that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ must be constant.

Comment: log(f(1)f(0))2=1log(f(1)f(0))2=1 this is not correct. And if f′(x)/f(x) is constant we cant proof anything

Comment: Think more. $f(1)=e\,f(0)\implies\log\left(\frac{f(1)}{f(0)}\right)^2=1$. Also, the constancy of the derivative implies the affinity of the function.

Comment: $
{Log}\left({{e}^{2}}\right)\mathrm{\ne}\hspace{0.33em}{1}
$
That why it is not correct

Comment: That's the square of the log, not the log of the square. That should be clear by the right side of the equation.

Comment: $
\begin{array}{l}
{{Log}\left({e}\right)\mathrm{\approx}\hspace{0.33em}{0}{\mathrm{.}}{4}{3}\hspace{0.33em}}\\
{{then}\hspace{0.33em}{Log}^{2}{\mathrm{(}}{e}{\mathrm{)}}\hspace{0.33em}{not}\hspace{0.33em}{equal}\hspace{0.33em}{1}}
\end{array}
$
How can you proof this equation?

Comment: $\log(e)=1$. Since it is the integral of $\frac1x$, $\log(x)$ is the natural log.

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\ln(f(x))'=\frac{1}{f(x)}f'(x)$$